# How to pass a Backbone function as a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have the requirement to pass a function in a Backbone view into another function in the same view. I used the following approach, which works fine for global functions. But when Backbone view instances are concerned, it does not work.

I believe the problem is that the passed function has incorrect context - note that `this` prints different objects in the console.

How to correctly pass the function and call the function in the correct context?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sachid/bkopgpfr/)

```
//Backbone view
mainFunc: function(){
    this.intermediateFunc(this.ABC);
}
intermediateFunc : function(callback){
    console.log(this); //prints the correct view
    callback();
}
ABC : function(){
    console.log(this); //prints 'window' when passed through a function
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind the appropriate `this` to your function. Something like this:

```
mainFunc: function(){
    this.intermediateFunc(this.ABC.bind(this));
}
```

Another common approach with callbacks is to allow the caller to supply the desired `this` and [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to use it:

```
mainFunc: function(){
    this.intermediateFunc(this.ABC, this);
},
intermediateFunc : function(callback, context) {
    console.log(this); //prints the correct view
    if(context)
        callback.call(context);
    else
        callback();
}
```

A variant of this could assume that `context` is supposed to be `this` in `intermediateFunc`:

```
mainFunc: function(){
    this.intermediateFunc(this.ABC, this);
},
intermediateFunc : function(callback, context) {
    console.log(this); //prints the correct view
    context = context || this;
    callback.call(context);
}
```

This might be useful if you're expecting `callback` to almost always be one of your view's methods (or a plain function).

Yet another approach would be to use the old `var _this = this` trick and pass an anonymous function to `intermediateFunc`:

```
mainFunc: function() {
    var _this = this;
    this.intermediateFunc(function() { return _this.ABC() });
}
```

Comment: Since `intermediateFunc` seems to be a function from the same object (`this.intermediateFunc`), it could be added that the callback can be called directly with `callback.call(this)`.

Comment: @EmileBergeron True. I'd probably fold that into the `second` option with `this` as the default `context`.